# Automatically add picture to uploaded document and then print it

Tags: printing, ms-word

How do add a small banner at the top of a uploaded word doc and then print it. The word doc needs to be resized to 90% for the banner to not cover the content. Convert it to pdf? Or script? Any ideas?
This is for ad-financed printing of worddoc thru a local printer.

Answer (score 0):

Softartisan's [OfficeWriter](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/) will give you that functionality.

You'll just be able to open the document, insert an ad, then print.

Although you could just pre-print the paper with ads already, which would save all the messing about?

Comment: The thing is that it should be different ads on the print depending on who the user is (girl/male/age/job/etc...)  This is for students. So if they register and then want to print a summary, they upload it, it gets resized so it can fit with ads on A4 and then the user can pick it up on our printer in their school..